# understanding this function c++

Tags: c++

i have this c++ function below
the function uses the first and last index and checks if the the following number is greater or less than the next index. if it is, then the x or y variable is replaced with the value of the current index.

this is the function:

```
template<class Type>
void funcExp(Type list[], int size) {
    Type x = list[0];
    cout << x << endl;
    Type y = list[size - 1];
    cout << y << endl;
    for(int j = 1; j < size; j++) {
        if(x < list[j]) x = list[j];

        if(y > list[size - 1 - j]) y = list[size - 1 - j];
    }
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
}
```

in my main i have this:

```
int list[10] = {5,3,2,10,4,19,45,13,61,11};
funcExp(List, 10);
```

i understand how the code works for numbers however i am unsure how this code works with strings. 
for example:

```
string strList[] = {"One", "Hello", "Four", "Three", "How", "Six"}; 
funcExp(strList, 6);
```

returns the following output:

```
x = three 
y = four
```

i thought that it was counting each character but i got a different output.
my question is, how does this function work an array of strings.

Comment: [Lexicographic order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

Comment: Do you know how string comparisons work?

Comment: Aside: your function is similar to [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)

Answer (score 2):

This function finds the maximum (`x`) and minimum (`y`) element in the array, by always keeping the value that "wins" in comparisons.

The comparisons are made using the default rules (unless you overloaded the operator), i.e. ordinary number comparison for integers and alphabetic ordering for strings.

---

Note that there is no reason to perform one of the searches left-to-right and the other right-to-left. The code below will be more efficient:

```
template<class Type>
void funcExp(Type list[], int size) {
    Type x = list[0];
    cout << x << endl;
    Type y = list[0];
    cout << y << endl;
    for(int j = 1; j < size; j++) {
        if(x < list[j]) x = list[j];

        else if(y > list[j]) y = list[j];
    }
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are compared by comparing letters in turn until a difference is found.

"Four" starts with 'F', which is less than any other first letter of your words

"Three" starts with 'T', which is greater than any other first letter of your words

This is the same procedure as [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)